# Cual es el error de este codigo - java

Tags: java

```
Genero obj=new Genero();
    int swG=0;
    while(swG==0) {
    System.out.print("Genero\nM : Masculino\nF : Femenino\n>>");
    obj.setTipoGenero(entrada.next().charAt(0));

       if ((obj.getTipoGenero() != 'm') || (obj.getTipoGenero() != 'M') || 
            (obj.getTipoGenero() != 'f') || (obj.getTipoGenero() != 'F')) {

            System.out.println("Seleccione la opcion correcta ");

        }else {
                swG=1;
        }
     }
```

Mi intención para el siguiente fragmento de codigo es que capture un char ya sea M o F segun el caso y por si el cual sea diferente a 'm' o 'M' o 'f' o 'F' que vuelva preguntar ya que no es la correcta por lo cual es el ciclo y si es correcta pues se prenda el swG y salga del ciclo y siga con el flujo del codigo, que pasa con el codigo?

Comment: Esto es más en el entendimiento de como funcionan los AND y OR. Imaginemos que colocamos o ingresamos un `'M'`, al hacer la comprobación en el if, en la primera condición ya se está cumpliendo la comparación, puesto que es diferente 'm', y entraría dentro del if, sin ni siquiera hacer las siguientes comprobaciones. Debes cambiar los `'||'` por `'&&'`.

Comment: @DiegoLoL si colega tienes razon y gracias por la descripción me ayudo a entender un poco mas de como usarlos en cada caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La condición está mal escrita. Debería ser así:

```
 if ((obj != 'm' && obj != 'M') && 
        (obj != 'f' && obj != 'F'))
```

Con eso lo que haces es comprobar por grupos, primero compruebas si es m o M y después si es f o F.

Comment: Si gracias tenias razon me falto un poco de logica en esa parte